# Program not building on Visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, g++

The above shows the error I am getting when I build main.cpp from Microsoft Visual Studio
main.cpp file

```
       #include <iostream>
    #include "catalan.h"
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int selection;
        int number;
       
        }
        return 0;
}
```

This is the catalan.h file :

```
#include "implementation.cpp"
int catalan(int n);
int fibonacci(int x);
void menu();
```

This is the implementation.cpp file

```
int catalan(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;
    int result = 0;
   

    return result;
}
int fibonacci(int x)
{
    return 0;
}
void menu()
{
    std::cout << "1. Do Catalan numbers" << std::endl;
 
}
```

I have removed some code from it for ease in readability. This same program is compiling
and running fine with g++ But when I put it on Microsoft Visual Studio it doesnt compile.
What could be the reason for it and how do it correct it ?  
  The image of error screenshot can be seen at -

[image: Snapshot of Error :-(]

Comment: Don't include `.cpp` files like you do in `#include "implementation.cpp"`. Include header files, compile `.cpp` files. Example: `g++ main.cpp implementation.cpp -o program_name`

Comment: Please, don't post text as images. The error messages can be easily copied if you use the `Output` tab (instead of the `Error List` tab).

Comment: @TedLyngmo This program is working fine with g++. But it doesn't run in Microsoft visual studio.

Comment: @puneeta Sure, but you still do it wrong. Remove the inclusion of `.cpp` files and compile like I showed instead. In VS, add the `.cpp` files to the project instead.

Comment: The problem is missing header files in implementation.cpp. You need to include `<iostream>` and remove `#include "implementation.cpp"` from `catalan.h`. Instead add `#include "catalan.h"` to `implementation.cpp`. Add header guards to `catalan.h`. You have unbalanced braces in `main.cpp`. Here is a working example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/V4s4qVhOMHrSQ7FR

Comment: I removed the `#include implementation.cpp` I got this error `implementation.cpp:21:10: error: ‘cout’ is not a member of ‘std’
   21 |     std::cout << "2. Do Fibonacci numbers (recursive)" << std::endl;` So it's the same error now I am getting with g++ which I get with visual studio

Comment: @puneeta You should always include the header files you need in your code. `implementation.cpp` seems to be using `std::cout` so it should `#include <iostream>`.

Comment: Yeah that worked for both g++ and Microsoft visual studio too. Thanks a lot

Comment: So the implementation file .cpp I should never include them in header. That's a bad practice as you suggested.  But then you need to pass two arguments to `g++ main.cpp implementaion.cpp` previously I was doing `g++ main.cpp`

Comment: @puneeta Indeed. And in IDE:s like VS you need to make sure that all `.cpp` files needed are actually included in the project so they get compiled and linked.

Comment: But how does Visual studio pick up implementation.cpp ? I mean like in g++ we are specifying main.cpp and implementation.cpp both. But in visual studio all I am doing is `Build->Build Solution` Looks like it picks up everything in the current project automatically

Comment: I have noticed several difference between g++ and visual studio compiler. Like if you write a function `int twice(int x){}` This will compile in g++ but throw an error in visual studio. That's weird. Although GNU claims that it's following the C++ specifications properly. So it's not an error on g++ part to not report this issue.

Comment: VS will compile the `.cpp` files you've added to the solution/project.

Comment: Thanks a lot one last question. If I am writing small programs I need several main methods. But it seems visual studio allows only one file to have main method in the project. That causes lot of difficulty in the sense I will have to create a new project for every small program I want to make. Is there an alternative to that ? Or I go and remove main methods from each file and keep it only in the file which I want to run. Both of which are cumbersome

Comment: Every executable (`.exe`) file can only have one `main`. It's the same in `g++`. I haven't tried it myself but perhaps you can collect all your small programs in one big solution? I don't know if that helps though. I personally create a new solution/project for each little program (I don't use the solution concept at all).

Comment: @TedLyngmo could you post it as an answer to this question. I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't include `.cpp` files like you do in `#include "implementation.cpp"`. Include header files and compile `.cpp` files.

When you've removed `#include "implementation.cpp` you may be required to add missing `#include`s to the `.cpp` file if it currently relies on that you've done `#include <iostream>` for example.

#### Compiling:

In `g++`, it would mean compiling this this:

```
g++ main.cpp implementation.cpp -o program_name
```

In Visual Studio it would mean adding the missing `.cpp` file to the project. It should be either `main.cpp` or `implementation.cpp`.